# What is this citrus fruit?

Tags: fruit, citrus

I had this delicious citrus fruit today that I'm having trouble identifying. I think it might be a tangelo, but I'm not sure. It was seedless and had a tangy/sour taste. Unlike a clementine, it did not peel very easily. It came with a delivery of other assorted fruits, so I don't know its geographical origin. In terms of size, it was about as big as a lime (too small to be a regular orange).

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are so many different types of citrus fruit... particularly so many varieties of oranges/clementines/tangerines... It would be miraculous if anyone could possibly pin this down exactly and know that they're correct. You've included a lot of good information to help, which is great... it may still be very difficult to pin down.

Comment: Thanks, Catija. I know it's a long shot, but I figure it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Looks like a tangelo to me, but I'm not game to say i'm 100% sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a honeybell. Also known as a tangelo.

Comment: Agree. Definitely looks like a Honeybell.

Comment: It could help to describe in what ways this fruit resembles a tangelo (the bump at the stem end; possible to peel although not as easy to peel as, say, a clementine; smaller than a navel orange, larger than a clementine; tart, aromatic taste; seedless, although I've met tangelos in both seedless and full-of-seeds varieties, sometimes in the same bag).

Comment: Also know as Minneola in my area.